# Checkbox automatically checked all when assigned non-empty variable to v-model

Tags: vue.js

Below is the code for my form to update the data that the user has submitted previously.

```
<div class="myLabel">Repeat on: </div> {{ data.repeatOn }}
<div class="myInput">
   <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" v-model="data.repeatOn" :checked="data.repeatOn.includes('1')"><label for="1">Monday</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" v-model="data.repeatOn" :checked="data.repeatOn.includes('2')"><label for="2">Tuesday</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3" v-model="data.repeatOn" :checked="data.repeatOn.includes('3')"><label for="3">Wednesday</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="4" v-model="data.repeatOn" :checked="data.repeatOn.includes('4')"><label for="4">Thursday</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" id="5" value="5" v-model="data.repeatOn" :checked="data.repeatOn.includes('5')"><label for="5">Friday</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="checkbox" id="6" value="6" v-model="data.repeatOn" :checked="data.repeatOn.includes('6')"><label for="6">Saturday</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="checkbox" id="7" value="7" v-model="data.repeatOn" :checked="data.repeatOn.includes('7')"><label for="7">Sunday</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

`data.repeatON` contains the previously checked value of the checkbox. Doing `{{ data.repeatOn }}` will display value like `1,2`

The problem is the code above will always check ALL check boxes. How do I make it only check the check boxes values that's stored inside `data.value`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `data.repeatOn` should define with unique name at HTML like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" v-model="data.repeatOn[1]" :checked="data.repeatOn.includes('1')"><label for="1">Monday</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" v-model="data.repeatOn[2]" :checked="data.repeatOn.includes('2')"><label for="2">Tuesday</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
//... data.repeatOn[n]
```

and at data

```
data() {
  return {
    data : {
      repeatOn : []
   }
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but upon further checking I found that the problem was because my data.repeatOn was string. I then convert it to array using split and leave v-model as `v-model="data.repeatOn` and it works. If I set v-model to `v-model="data.repeatOn[1]"` and so on as you mentioned above, it doesn't work.